# Pseudo-random orthogonal matrix generation

Tags: random-generation, matrix

A little while back, J.M. [suggested](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/how-to-efficiently-generate-positive-semi-definite-correlation-matrices/2786#2786) using the [Stewart](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2156882) algorithm for generating $n$ by $n$ pseudo random orthogonal matrices in $O(n^2)$ time. He further noted that this methodology is implemented in Nick Higham's matrix computation toolbox ([matlab](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/mctoolbox/)). Now this package contains a bunch of .m files. Could anyone direct me to which one implements the pseudorandom orthogonal matrix generator? Alternatively, would anyone know of a R implementation of this algorithm?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's in the Test Matrix Toolbox, not the Matrix Computation Toolbox. The M-file `qmult.m` (premultiplication by a Haar-distributed pseudorandom orthogonal matrix) can be found [here](http://www.netlib.org/toms/694) or [here](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/test_matrix/qmult.m).

Comment: Thanks alot (both for the clever initial suggestion and for the folow thru).

Comment: No problem, kwak; remember only that it does premultiplication, though modifying the algorithm to do postmultiplication shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: M.:> it should be okay: i only need Q (i.e. qmult(eye(p)))