# Generating and verifying uniformly distrubuted orthogonal matrices

Tags: matrix, random-generation, random-matrix

I would like to generate a uniformly distributed $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix.  There seems to be several such methods; see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2972/pseudo-random-orthogonal-matrix-generation) and the oft-cited paper by [Stewart](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0717034).  Using a [QR decompostion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix#Randomization) of a matrix of normally-distributed variables seems to be another popular method.

However, I am being careful, because apparently it is not hard to generate a subtly-wrong distribution. [This paper](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fnotices%2F200705%2Ffea-mezzadri-web.pdf&ei=HRoIUqz0F6GriAeemoCwCQ&usg=AFQjCNESHv00uIyATuY1NETwTfH5IO1fhQ&sig2=xjSNWNlu8LnYPwe51rZphQ&bvm=bv.50500085,d.aGc) by Mezzadri demonstrates how it can be wrong for a random *unitary* matrix.

So, I would like to ask:

- What implementation issues do I need to be aware of when applying either the QR or the Stewart method?
- Are these indeed the fastest methods? (I want to generate $15 \times 15$ matrices on an embedded platform, so both CPU and cache are of the essence)
- How to I verify that the generated distribution is correct?

The last question is important - How do I verify that distribution is correct? What do I need to look for? How can I implement such a test, even if visually for (say) a $2 \times 2$ or $3 \times 3$ matrix?